# usage of macros in dbt_project config-version:2

Tags: macros, dbt

Our dbt_project.yml file, config-version: 1 has two variables across different incremental models, for which one we use a macro called *today()*

```
vars:
  start_date: '{{ today(offset_days=-1) }}'
  end_date: '2999-12-31'
```

When testing the migration to dbt 0.17.2, config-version:2, we face the following issue

```
Running with dbt=0.17.2
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  Could not render {{ today(offset_days=-1) }}: 'today' is undefined
```

The macro we built it end of last year. I believe dbt changed the way macro variables are referenced, however not sure how to tackle this.

```
-- returns current hour in YYYY-MM-DD-HH format,
-- optionally offset by N days (-N or +N) or M hours (-M or +M)
{%- macro current_hour(offset_days=0, offset_hours=0) -%}
  {%- set now = modules.datetime.datetime.now(modules.pytz.utc) -%}
  {%- set dt = now + modules.datetime.timedelta(days=offset_days, hours=offset_hours) -%}
  {{- dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H") -}}
{%- endmacro -%}

-- returns current day in YYYY-MM-DD format,
-- optionally offset by N days (-N or +N) or M hours (-M or +M)
{%- macro today(offset_days=0, offset_hours=0) -%}
  {{- current_hour(offset_days, offset_hours)[0:10] -}}
{%- endmacro -%}

-- accepts a timestamp string and returns a timestamo string
-- formatted like 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US', e.g. '2019-11-02 06:11:42.690000'
{%- macro dt_to_utc(ts_string) -%}
  TO_CHAR({{ ts_string }}::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this out locally and got it to work. In addition to the things to check above, have you also moved `vars` to be at the same level as `models` in your `dbt_project.yml` file ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/migration-guide/upgrading-to-0-17-0/#using-config-version-2))?

```
models:
  ...

vars:
  start_date: '{{ today(offset_days=-1) }}'
  end_date: '2999-12-31'
```

I'm actually surprised this works! Variables are best for hard-coded objects rather than dynamic objects.

I'm curious — why not just call the macro directly instead of using the variable?

Current:

```sql
where created_at >= {{ var('start_date') }}
```

Proposed:

```sql
where created_at >= {{ today(offset_days=-1) }}
```

That being said, my spidey-senses are tingling a little here — this code makes your dbt project non-idempotent — if your production run of dbt stopped for a few days straight, this filter would result in missing data.

Typically we avoid a pattern like this. Instead, we use our existing versions of models to build any cutoff dates — you can see more examples of it [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models/#filtering-rows-on-an-incremental-run).

Comment: I have followed the migration guide. I do think as well it requires a re-write following the example you provided. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, just some basics that come to mind first because I hadn't made all these changes when I moved to 0.17.2 and had some similar issue:

1. Are you listing your macro path in the `dbt_project.yml`?

   Ex. `macro-paths: ["macros"]`
2. I assume you added `config-version: 2` to your `dbt_project.yml`?
3. Try double quotes?
   `"{{ today(offset_days=-1) }}"`

Optional: Did you build out a macro "schema.yml"

Comment: 1 to 3 are yes.